# How to use iscelleditable method in java netbeans

Tags: java, mysql

Hey I'm a Java newbie so I am asking how can I implement the is cell editable method in java Every time I try to implement it I get an Array Index Out Of Bounds error My Table is generated randomly as per a database setup & I want to set the 1st 2nd 3rd column not to  be editable

```
//Get columns if data has been recorded for that ticket 
public void getColumns() {
    //jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null,new String[]{""}));
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    String query="Select subjectName from subject where class ='"+c+"' order by subjectName asc";
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(query);
        tableModel.addColumn("FirstName");//0
        tableModel.addColumn("MiddleName");//1
        tableModel.addColumn("SurName");//2
        tableModel.addColumn("Examdate");//3
        tableModel.addColumn("Examtype");//4
        tableModel.addColumn("Stream");//5
        tableModel.addColumn("Avg");//6
        tableModel.addColumn("Total");//7
        tableModel.addColumn("Position");//8

        while(rs.next()){
            //Local varibles are assigned to values gained in the database          
            String columnName=rs.getString(1);
            tableModel.addColumn(columnName);
        }

        jTable1.setModel(tableModel);
        jTable1.setModel(dtm);
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,se.getMessage());
    }

}    
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0) {
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
return false;
}
};
```

The data  from the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th 5th and 6th column come from the database and the rest is manually inputted by the user
The method responsible for retrieving this data is

```
//gets names avg,examtype date strm and results
public void getResults(){
int pos=0;
int x=0;
int index=9;
String query="Select name,mname,sname,examtype,examdate,Stream,avg,total,pos "   
+ "from result"+c+" where examtype='"+en+"' and stream='"+strm+"'   
order by total desc";
DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
try{
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
//Local varibles are assigned to values gained in the database

String fnamee=rs.getString(1);
String mnamee=rs.getString(2);
String snamee=rs.getString(3);
String examname=rs.getString(4);
String examdate=rs.getString(5);
String Stream=rs.getString(6);
double avg=rs.getDouble(7);
int total=rs.getInt(8);
pos++;
//Until seen false a row will be added and display data from database
model.addRow(new Object[]
{fnamee,mnamee,snamee,examname,examdate,Stream,avg,total,pos});
}
//Hides unwanted columns
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(0);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(0);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setWidth(0);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(0);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(0);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setWidth(0);  
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMinWidth(0);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMaxWidth(0);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setWidth(0); 
//method responisble for udapting  the position
positionInsert();
}
```

See table here
[image]

Comment: Can you add an example that concentrates on the `JTable`? I.e. the data could be a `List<List<String>>` filled in manually. And we should be able to run the code as-is.

Comment: The data for column 0,1,2,3,4,5, comes from the database while  the rest are manually entered when the save button is pressed it alters the data in the database and the position average and total changes as per the data entered Now since  the first 5 columns data are from the database I want to make them not  to be editable manually how can I do this ?

Comment: Yes, it comes from the database *in your code*. I don't have your database though. I don't want to build it either. Please separate your Swing view from your database model so **we can help you solve your problem**.

Comment: As a separate note, these ways to decompose the bigger problems into smaller ones, this is exactly, how you'll be able to solve your problems independently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for my Problem I figured it out

```
   //Get columns if data has been recorded for that ticket 
    public void getColumns(){

        //Start
         DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        if(column<10){
        return false;
        }
        else{
           return true;
        }

    }
    };

    //end

     String query="Select subjectName from subject where class ='"+c+"' order by subjectName asc";

          try{
    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(query);
    tableModel.addColumn("FirstName");//0
    tableModel.addColumn("MiddleName");//1
    tableModel.addColumn("SurName");//2
    tableModel.addColumn("Examdate");//3
    tableModel.addColumn("Examtype");//4
    tableModel.addColumn("Stream");//5
    tableModel.addColumn("Avg");//6
    tableModel.addColumn("Grade");//7
    tableModel.addColumn("Total");//8
    tableModel.addColumn("Position");//9
    while(rs.next()){
    //Local varibles are assigned to values gained in the database      
    String columnName=rs.getString(1);

   tableModel.addColumn(columnName);

   }

   //Sets new Tablemodel

  jTable1.setModel(tableModel);

    }
```